# In ggplot2: How to pair dodge settings to connect individual data points with geom_line when using fill, alpha and facets for violin plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have an example data set like this. My real data is much larger.

```
df <- data.frame(ID   = rep(c(1:8),each = 8 ),
                 var1 = factor(rep(rep(c('1','2'), each = 4),8)),
                 var2 = factor(rep(c("EXP", "CTR"), 32)), 
                 var3 = factor(rep(c('X','Z','Z','X'), 16)),
                 var4 = factor(rep(rep(c('G1','G1','G2','G2'),each=8),2)),
                 var5 = factor(rep(rep(c('GA','GB','GB','GA'),each=8),2)),
                 value = sample(0:100, 64, rep = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(ID,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

What I want to achieve is to connect the individual data points of the jitter in the graph, particularly between X and Z.

```
#set position of the jitter
pos_jit=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.3, dodge.width = 0.9, seed=1)

ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill=var2, alpha=var3)) +theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(var4,var5), nrow=4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='Set1')+ # scale_fill_manual(values=c("#49111c","#bddbd0"))+
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0.3),guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))) +
  geom_violin(position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_point(               size=2, color='grey',  position=pos_jit) +
  #geom_path(aes(group=interaction(ID,var1)), position=pos_jit) +
  geom_line(aes(group=ID), position=pos_jit) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "crossbar", width = .5, size=0.4, color = "black", position = position_dodge(.9), show.legend=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position= "top")+theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
  ylab('RT in ms') + xlab('')
```

The graph I get looks like the one below. However, the lines appear at random positions. I have the impression that the problem comes with the fill and alpha, right?
A solution without setting the dodges manually into the data is preferable. If that is not possible, how do it need to set the dodges? A generally valid formula would be great.

[image]

Comment: Not sure - but your ID variable is constant.

Comment: True. I am going to adjust that.

Comment: Could you try moving the `group=ID` from `geom_line(aes())` to `ggplot(aes())`? You may then need `group=NULL` in `geom_violin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made:

1. `group` moved from `geom_line(aes())` to `ggplot(aes())`
2. `group = NULL` in `geom_violin()`
3. `set.seed(2)` for reproducibility
4. `group = str_c(ID, var1, var2)` to pair light and dark points
5. `str_c(var1, var2, var3)` as `x` variable to shift dark points left
6. A little bit of styling, e.g. `theme()`

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c(1:8), each = 8),
  var1 = factor(rep(rep(c("1", "2"), each = 4), 8)),
  var2 = factor(rep(c("EXP", "CTR"), 32)),
  var3 = factor(rep(c("X", "Z", "Z", "X"), 16)),
  var4 = factor(rep(rep(c("G1", "G1", "G2", "G2"), each = 8), 2)),
  var5 = factor(rep(rep(c("GA", "GB", "GB", "GA"), each = 8), 2)),
  value = sample(0:100, 64, rep = TRUE)
) %>%
  arrange(ID, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)

pos_jit <- position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 1, dodge.width = 0.9, seed = 1)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(str_c(var1, var2, var3), value, fill = var2, alpha = var3, group = str_c(ID, var1, var2))) +
  geom_violin(position = "dodge", aes(group = NULL)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "grey", position = pos_jit) +
  geom_line(position = pos_jit) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = "mean", geom = "crossbar", width = .5, linewidth = 0.4, color = "black",
    position = position_dodge(.9), show.legend = FALSE, aes(group = NULL)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(var4, var5), nrow = 4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(
    range = c(1, 0.3),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(y = "RT in ms", x = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this option. Unfortunately, it does not do what I intended. I also added  , aes(group=NULL) to the stat_summary to fix it a bit. The good thing. The lines are now matched with the dots! : ) Two problems remain or opened up.

Comment: 1. The jitter is not placed where the violin plots are any more, but in between. 2. Lets have a look at the two blue violin plots right down. There are four dots that should be placed within the violin plots. Each of the dark ones should be connected to one of the light ones (I think this works already). However, there should be only two lines (four at the moment). Only the same ID should be connected.

Comment: The update looks great. I like the upper figure more. Only that there are still 3 lines instead of two. And i was wondering why the points have changed? The dark one should always be on the left (as the dark var2) and the light ones on the right side. Do we have to adjust the arrange order?

Comment: I've made a combination `x` variable to keep dark points to the left and light points to the right. Does that work for you?

Comment: You could potentially dispense with the legend now with `legend.position = "none"` in `theme()`.

Comment: Looks great! I just need to get the original x axis back with  
+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=rep(c('1', '2'),4))

Comment: I noticed that we now got much more labels on the x axis than before. So I made a workaround like this scale_x_discrete(labels=rep(c('1', '2'),each = 4)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(color=c("transparent","black","transparent","transparent","transparent","transparent","black","transparent")))

Comment: Also I notice in my real data that the factor levels were not always ordered by the alphabetical order as in the simple example. But this made the trick: x=fct_relevel(str_c(session, task, sequence, sep=' '),
                         'place your combined levels here in the right order',)